# What is Peak Working Set in windows task manager

Tags: windows, memory

I'm confused about the windows task manager memory overview.
in the general memory overview it shows "in use" 7.9gb (in my sample)
[image: windows task manager].

I've used process explorer to sum up the used memory and it shows me the following: 
[image: process monitor]

Since this is the nearest number to the 7.9gb of the task manager, i guess this value is shown there.

Now my question: 
What is the **Peak working set**?

If i hoover over the column in task manager, it says:

[image]

and the [microsoft help](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/what-do-the-task-manager-memory-columns-mean) says *Maximum amount of working set memory used by the process.*

Is it now the effective used memory of all processes, or is it the maximum of memory which *was* used by all process?

Comment: This question IMO is better placed in SuperUser site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number you refer to is "Memory used by processes, drivers and the operating system" [[source]](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2013/08/09/task-manager-in-windows-server-2012-and-windows-8.aspx).

This is an easy but somewhat vague description. A somewhat similar description would be the total amount of memory that is not free, or part of the buffer cache, or part of the standby list.

It is **not** the maximum memory used at some time ("peak"), it's a coincidence that you have roughly the same number there. It is the presently used amount (used by "everyone", that is all programs and the OS).

The peak working set is a different thing. The working set is the amount of memory in a process (or, if you consider several processes, in all these processes) that is currently in physical memory. The *peak* working set is, consequently, the maximum value so far seen.
A process may allocate more memory than it actually ever commits ("uses"), and most processes will commit more memory than they have in their working set at one time. This is perfectly normal. Pages are moved in and out of working sets (and into the standby list) to assure that the computer, which has only a finite amount of memory, always has enough reserves to satisfy any memory needs.

Comment: :Can you please share your inputs here:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34858626/integrity-not-maintained-working-set-and-peak-working-set-values-for-a-process

Answer (score 2):

The memory figures in question aren't actually a reliable indicator of how much memory a process is using.

A brief explanation of each of the memory relationships:

- **Private Bytes** are what the process is allocated, also with pagefile usage.
- Working Set is the non-paged **Private Bytes** plus memory-mapped files.
- **Virtual Bytes** are the **Working Set** plus paged **Private Bytes** and
  standby list.

In answer to your question the peak working set is the maximum amount of physical RAM that was assigned to the process in question.

~ Update ~

Available memory is defined as the sum of the standby list plus free memory. There is far more to total memory usage than the sum all process working sets. Because of this and due to memory sharing this value is not generally very useful.

The virtual size of a process is the portion of a process virtual address space that has been allocated for use. There is no relationship between this and physical memory usage.

Private bytes is the portion of a processes virtual address space that has been allocated for private use. It does not include shared memory or that used for code. There is no relationship between this value and physical memory usage either.

Working set is the amount of physical memory in use by a process. Due to memory sharing there will be some double counting in this value.

The terms mentioned above aren't really going to mean very much until you understand the basic concepts in Windows memory management. Have a look [HERE](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/11/17/3155406.aspx) for some further reading.

Comment: But if i e.g. use  GC.Collect() in a .net application, it will decrease the peak working set without stopping the process. This means to me that peak working set is not the maximum amount of physical RAM that was assigned.